# What's stopping me from attacking the network by renting 51% of the stake for a few blocks?

Tags: blockchain, proof-of-stake, consensus, attacks

The Ethereum market cap today is about $200bn. Theoretically, buying 51% of it would cost a stunning $100bn. Good luck getting that money hahah.

However, I could ideally rent 51% of the staked eth for an hour, for only $2mn (formula: `10^11 * 15% / (24 * 365)` ; that's nothing!!). In this hour, I could give myself a few $bn worth of Ethereum, for a huge net profit.

I'm sure this is a well studied attack. How does Ethereum defend against it?

Answer (score 0):

It's not practically feasible:

1. You need to get > $100B dollars from somewhere, and you want to pay only $2M for it. This is outside the realms of even large prime brokerages.
2. You need to actually buy the Ether, and hold it on-chain. Naturally trying to buy $100B of Ether buying is going to push the price up...a lot. So you're going to need a lot more than $100B. Also, other people are going to see the price rising and hop on the trend. So rough guess, at least $500B, maybe more?
3. You can't buy this all in one shot, you're going to have to spread out your buying over time. While you do this buying, you're exposed to price risk. Over the long term the price will go up because of your enormous buying, but in the short term there will be fluctuations. So there are paths where you go to your lenders and say "Remember that $100B you lent me and I'm paying you $2M for? Yeah so at the moment I've lost like $500M, but don't worry, I'm sure it will come back." So maybe you could get away with posting maybe only $10B-$50B of capital and leverage it up to $100B-$500B?
4. Even assuming the financing works out, you have to actually find 51% of all Ether to buy, and also assume that no one will care and take drastic measures like forking the chain to fight you off.

Basically, when you say "Theoretically, buying 51% of it would cost a stunning $100B", that "Theoretically" is doing a lot of lifting.

Comment: 5. Once you own 51%, the price is going to collapse as everyone loses faith in Ethereum.  You'll be lucky to get even a few thousand dollars back once you've made your attack and are trying to monetize it.